# Woocommerce 'high to low sorting option not working correctly'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce 'high to low sorting option not working correctly' rest all filter are woking as expected.

What i did :- **1) added bellow line of code**
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'modify_woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby');

```
function modify_woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    if( empty( $orderby ) ) {
        return 'price-desc';
    }

    return $orderby;
}

      **2) went to Woocommerce – status – tools and On this page, clean Transients, regenerate Product Lookup tables, Recount terms, and update database i runned cron job manually.**
```

Answer (score 0):

1"
at the first check this way:
delete you're code and try this :
go to  appearance -> Customize -> WooCommerce -> Product Catalog -> Default Product Sorting
Click on the custom filter‌ ( you want )
If this method does not work, try the second way

2"you can use this function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'default_catalog_ordering_desc', 10, 2 );
function default_catalog_ordering_desc( $q, $query ){
    if( $q->get( 'orderby' ) == 'menu_order title' )
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
}
```

Comment: hi @Negar Kazemnejad thanks for your time i tried both methods but the result is same sorting not working

Comment: I had a similar problem before
If you use templates, check the code from inside the function.php inside the template once...
my code is different!

Comment: check this document :
https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-12